# Is it possible to change the input text size with crispy filter

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have started using `crispy-forms` in my Django project. For authentication, I am currently using `django.contrib.auth.views.login` as an view and a custom template for rendering.

In order to use the `crispy-forms`, I just made the following changes in template.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>You can login here</p>
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Now, my question is that with the above template, login input text widget spans across the entire width of screen. Can I change the widget size with `crispy` filter? What has to be changed if I have to use `django.contrib.auth.views.login` functionality with custom layout from `crispy-form`

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the visual representation alone, have you considered overriding the css?

Comment: Not really, I was just wondering if there is any built-in method using crispy-forms. I'm new to crispy-forms, custom css is one way. But let's say, if we have to do it with crispy-forms, then what should be the approach other than using crispy filter?